# excel vba call multiple subroutines in select case

Tags: excel, vba, call, subroutine

If I have the following code:

```
Select Case Number

  Case 1: Call Subroutine1()
  Case 2: Call Subroutine2()
  Case 3: Call Subroutine3()
  Case 4: Call Subroutine4()
  Case 5: Call Subroutine5()
  Case 6: Call Subroutine6()

End Select
```

and I want to call several subroutines in case 1:

How can it be done?

best, US

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Select Case Number

  Case 1: 
    Call Subroutine1a()
    Call Subroutine1b()
    Call Subroutine1c()

  Case 2: Call Subroutine2()
  Case 3: Call Subroutine3()
  Case 4: Call Subroutine4()
  Case 5: Call Subroutine5()
  Case 6: Call Subroutine6()

End Select
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
Select Case Number

  Case 1: 
      Call Subroutine1a()
      Call Subroutine1b()
  Case 2: Call Subroutine2()
  Case 3: Call Subroutine3()
  Case 4: Call Subroutine4()
  Case 5: Call Subroutine5()
  Case 6: Call Subroutine6()

End Select
```

Answer (score -1):

You can have as many statement in each Case match as you like;

```
Select Case Number
  Case 1
    Call Subroutine1()
    Call Subroutine2()
  Case 2: Call Subroutine2()
  ...
```